# Problem with the create of the c# project ، I can't click OK

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a Problem with the create of the c# project ، I can't click OK
So what can I do to solve it ??

[image]

Comment: there seems to be a malformed drop down top-left; I wonder if that is the problem? however, based on the tags and screenshot, you're using a decade-old IDE; *why* are you doing that?

Comment: Upgrade to Visual Studio 2019.   The Community Edition is free and probably contains everything you need.

Comment: Can you run visual studio as Administrator. Check if it works.